# MySQL STR_TO_DATE for strings with just month and year or just year

Tags: mysql, string, date, type-conversion, str-to-date

I have a column called ReleaseDate (which is a string). Most of them are in the form of `%e %M %Y` (25 May 1979), but there are a few where it is just `%M %Y` (May 1979) or `%Y` (1979). Unfortunately, it doesn't seem the `STR_TO_DATE` works with just `%M %Y`. Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT ReleaseDate,
       CASE
         WHEN STR_TO_DATE(ReleaseDate, '%e %M %Y') IS NULL
         THEN CASE
                WHEN STR_TO_DATE(ReleaseDate, '%M %Y') IS NULL
                THEN STR_TO_DATE(ReleaseDate, 'Y')
                ELSE STR_TO_DATE(ReleaseDate, '%M %Y')
              END
         ELSE STR_TO_DATE(ReleaseDate, '%e %M %Y')
       END,
       STR_TO_DATE(ReleaseDate, '%M %Y')
FROM   MyTable
```

But it returns the following:

```
 RealeaseDate           CASE           STR_TO_DATE
 -------------------------------------------------
| 20 May 2003 | 5/20/2003 12:00:00 AM |  {null}   |
| 16 May 2000 | 5/16/2000 12:00:00 AM |  {null}   |
| May 1976    |        {null}         |  {null}   |
 -------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any workaround for this?

**EDIT**

To add to this, I have attempted to change `sql_mode` by taking out `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` and even adding in `ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`, but this also didn't work. According to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date, I was not able to use the following example either:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('9','%m');
```

which also returns `{null}`.

I have also tried setting `sql_mode` to be blank. By running:

```
SELECT version();
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode global, @@SESSION.sql_mode session
```

I get:

```
 version() *
-------------
| 5.6.14    |
-------------

 global session
----------------
|      |       |
----------------
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) OR CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 22)`

Comment: I don't understand this...I have dates already. I don't see how this will solve anything.

Comment: Also, `GETDATE()` is MSSQL I think, not MySQL, which uses `NOW()` instead.